# Established user privilege page typo

Tags: discussion, privileges, spelling

There's a minor typo on the [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) page:

> User hover cards allow you to show off your **awesome** to other users in our network.

Should "*awesome*" be corrected to *awesomeness* or some other synonym?

Comment: The real question here is: **do you have awesome?**

Comment: In Soviet Russia, **awesome** shows *YOU* off!

Comment: Awesome can be a fleeting state... :)

Comment: Welcome to the Internet.  You must be new :P

Comment: Fair enough - changed question title & switched "bug" tag to "discussion"

Comment: Awesome is being used as a noun, therefor the correct place for this question is on english.se

Comment: @Matthew I thought this went against the professionalism SO tries to convey.

Comment: @Farseeker [Therefore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefore) != [Therefor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a site for programmers is bound to be filled with pedants who are offended at the slightest little mistake, it would awesome if this was fixed.

Comment: Agreed. It would awesome.

Comment: Fixing a typo is awe inspiring??? Meh.

Comment: @TimPost But you see, we can get our daily quota of awesome after they fix the typo, so indeed it will awesome!

Comment: @Yi Jiang - Well, I guess +1 for [recursive awesomeness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105297/established-user-privilege-page-typo) then.

Answer (score 2):

A more in-depth article, devoid of said "creative liberty", is available on [Meta Stack Overflow's privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), and will eventually be rolled out to the other sites.